# tenserflow работает экстремально медленно

Tags: python, tensorflow

установил tensorflow-GPU для Python 3.6 (64 bit). Включил тестовый файл object_detection_tutorial.py для веб-камеры. Скорость обработки 1 кадр за 20 с. На ютубе тот же алгоритм обрабатывается в 400 раз быстрее. Почему у меня скорость низкая? На tensorflow cpu та же самая ситуация.
Tensorflow-gpu 1.10, CUDA 9.2 (пробовал с CUDA 9.0), cuDNN 7.2.1 (for CUDA 9.2), protoc 3.4.0 (версия 3.6.0 в командной строке не загружается), обновил драйвер на видеокарту GE Force 1080 (ОЗУ 16 Гб, i7 6700K), windows 10.

Comment: питон никогда не был очень быстрым сам по себе, в вашем случае вероятнее всего надо смотреть настройки fps в тестовом файле который запускаете.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `cuDNN v7.0` и `CUDA 9.0`

Comment: пробовал. Ютубер на питоне с именно этим кодом получал 20 кадров в секунду

Comment: вы уверены, что tensorflow у вас использует GPU, а не CPU?

Comment: @MaxU да, проверял, используется GPU